# ParcelJS: Error: Does not have node 17172 when running dev server

Tags: javascript, parceljs

seem to having an issue with ParcelJS. It was working and the build compiling with no issues. Went to restart the development server and now have an issue and it wont work. It throws the following error:

```
Error: Does not have node 17172
    at RequestGraph._assertHasNodeId (/Users/ollienorris/Documents/gsap-test/node_modules/@parcel/graph/lib/Graph.js:449:13)
    at RequestGraph.getNodeIdsConnectedTo (/Users/ollienorris/Documents/gsap-test/node_modules/@parcel/graph/lib/Graph.js:77:10)
    at RequestGraph.respondToFSEvents (/Users/ollienorris/Documents/gsap-test/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/RequestTracker.js:459:26)
    at loadRequestGraph (/Users/ollienorris/Documents/gsap-test/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/RequestTracker.js:873:18)
    at async RequestTracker.init (/Users/ollienorris/Documents/gsap-test/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/RequestTracker.js:822:17)
    at async Parcel._init (/Users/ollienorris/Documents/gsap-test/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/Parcel.js:188:28)
    at async Parcel.watch (/Users/ollienorris/Documents/gsap-test/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/Parcel.js:260:7)
    at async run (/Users/ollienorris/Documents/gsap-test/node_modules/parcel/lib/cli.js:283:9)
```

I have had a Google of the issue, but there doesn't seem to be anything there to help me fix the issue.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the .parcel-cache folder and restarting the app sorted this issue out